problema con jerarquía de paquetes en eclipse
al intentar crear un paquete dentro de otro paquete eclipse no me deja, al parecer hay varias personas que les ha pasado este problema pero no he visto ninguna solución a este tema. (sí, he intentado desde el explorador de paquetes poner click derecho - new package pero no hay caso!! ayuda


Creo que tu problema radica en como tienes configurada la visualización de la jerarquía de paquetes (como 'Flat' en lugar de 'Hierarchical').
En la esquina superior derecha del 'Package Explorer', justo a la izquierda de la opción de minimizar, tienes el 'View Menu', los 3 puntitos apilados verticalmente. Haz clic ahí, después en 'Package Presentation' y por último marca la opción de 'Hierarchical', para que los paquetes se te presenten de forma anidada.

